# CHKDSK erases VHDX That threw Corrupted/Unreadable Error

Tags: windows-server-2012, data-recovery, chkdsk, vhdx

A windows 7 Virtual machine instance running on a windows 12 server had a 'blue screen of death' with a REGISTRY_ERROR (Code 51).

After several unsuccessful reboots (successfully to safe-mode but could not a safe-mode with networking) a CHKDSK was run on the drive that stored the VirtualMachine's hard disk (.VHDX)
Once CHKDSK ran the file system shows the vhdx file as having 0 bytes and the Virtual machine will no longer start nor the drive mount.

Is there a way to recover the virtual disk (VHDX)? and Why did CHKDSK cause this?`

Comment: The file was corrupted somehow. It’s probably not likely it can be recovered, because the file would be huge and all the blocks would have to be intact to use it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to remove the drive and make a clone to another drive before you do anything else.

Chkdsk must have found errors and tried to correct - clearly failed.

Once you have cloned, you can remount your drive and right click on the VHDX file and select restore previous versions - if there are any available, it will give you the dates.

If not, then you either need to restore from backup or, if the data is important, look at professional data recovery. Working with 0 byte files is quite difficult, so make sure the company knows how to work with them.